# Incorrect bitstream to long conversion in C

Tags: c, file

**What I am doing:**

I am trying to read Byte-By-Byte from a .wav file and trying to show some information about the header present in the file. (For my project work).

**My Code (A small Part) :-**

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char a[4],temp[4],i,j;
    int test;
    long value=0;
    FILE *file;
    file=fopen("hellomono.wav","rb");
    // 
    //4 bytes - chunkID @ "RIFF"
    fread(a,4,1,file);
    printf("ChunkID is: %s\n", a);

    //4 bytes - ChunkSize
    fread(a,4,1,file);
    for (i=0;i<4;i++) value=value+((long)a[i]<<(8*i));
    printf("ChunkSize is: %ld bits \n", value);
    printf("%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n",a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3] );

    value=0;
}
```

**My Problems:-**

1. Now as the **ChunkSize** is of size 4 bytes and in little endian format, I am converting it into long value to print the correct value.
   The `printf` statement with hex output shows: `ffffffb4:4f:02:00` but I have specified the format as `%02x` so it should show hex at most of 2 value, which is good for part `4f:02:00` but the first part `ffffffb4` is not so. Why?
2. Let's assume the 4 Byte read is `b4:4f:02:00` in little endian, thats `0x00024FB4` in big endian, its **151476** but in the code, the 2nd last printf prints the following: `ChunkSize is: 151220 bits` , why?

Thank You.

Comment: Use `%hhx` to show `char` arguments as hex. And you should use `unsigned char` or - better - `stdint.h` types and `inttypes.h` format specifiers for fixed bitwidth types.

Answer (score 1):

> but I have specified the format as %02x so it should show hex at most of 2 value

It does not mean that, it means it shows at least 2 digits padded with `0` if necessary. Cast the argument to `unsigned char` to get rid of the `f` digits.

Comment: Seriously, that fixed both my problems...bravo.